# Popups too small and with scroll bars in Genexus

Tags: genexus

In genexus (17u6, with wwp, but it's a problem even without this) when I call a panel as a popup, it is systematically slightly too big for the frame that contains it and this creates hideous scroll bars

[image]

I believe that genexus creates the iframes slightly larger than the panel (928px vs 900px), but still not enough

Even if I try to create the popup indicating a size I have the same problem

```
&window.Object = WLESL000.Create()
&window.Autoresize = false
&window.Width = 1430
&window.Open()
```

[image]

1430 becomes an iframe of 1458, not enough

I tried to work with classes, but the only thing I managed to get was a fixed size popup big enough to fit the whole thing, but that's not a satisfactory solution. Is there a way to modify the behavior of genexus in the creation of the iframe or in any case to make him eliminate the scroll bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking to wwp support I found that the simpler way is to create a new class called gx-popup-document following this https://docs.workwithplus.com/com.wiki.wiki?3321,Change+the+width+of+a+PopUp,
and adding to the custom properties:

min-width: 1200px !important; overflow: hidden !important

This hide the scroll bars of the popup

This is another possibility, but I didn't try it

https://docs.workwithplus.com/com.wiki.wiki?3633,Popup+with+Web+Component+in+User+Action,

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar problem using Genexus (16 U10) with WWP 13. The solution was to create a Javascript external object that was responsible for hiding the scrollbar setting `document.body.style.overflowX` to `'hidden'`. Maybe it might be interesting for you to try this solution, adding `$("iframe").height(*desired height*)` as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to use windows.open instead of popup? I think that with windows.open you can hidden the scrollbars.
Bye
Danar